# VFS FileObject not able to delete file

Tags: java, file, vfs, filesystemexception

I have org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject in my code and after the task is complete I need to delete the file. for which FileObject  has delete () method. But it throws FileSystemException.

I did check if there there is file exist, and further delete the file.

```
FileObject doc2Delete = VFS.getManager().resolveFile("C:\test.pdf");
if (doc2Delete.exists()) {
try {
doc2Delete.delete();
} catch (FileSystemException fse) {
fse.printStackTrace();
}
```

I expect the file to be deleted but it throws FileSystemException .

Answer (score 0):

On checking file status, it was found not closed. So started working after closing the file

```
if(doc2Delete.isContentOpen()){
doc2Delete.close()
}
```